# Sequence of closures not running the way I expected

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, firebase, asynchronous

I have two different data classes in firebase that I need to combine into one class for a certain feed in my app. So I used closures to make a step by step process to get info from the database, manipulate it and combine into one array. My function that gets all the data is working fine but I need that function to be called first then x,y and z happen.. the problem is the wrong function is being called first even though I am attempting to use completion handlers. Please help if I am doing something wrong. Thank you in advance.

Here is the function that needs to be run first to get all the data from Firebase:

```
func getUserLeagues(_ completion: ()->()) {

    userLeagues.getGolferLeagues {
        print("Step 1")
        for league in self.userLeagues.leagues {
            print("FOR IN League ID: \(league.leagueID)")
            self.getLeagueInfo(leagueID: league.leagueID, completion: {
                print("Step 2")

            })
        }
        print("League Info Code Run")

    }
    completion()
}


//Get league Info
func getLeagueInfo(leagueID: String, completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    REF_leagueInfo.child(leagueID).observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            self.leagueInfo.removeAll()
            for snap in snapshot {
                print("SNAP: \(snap)")

                if let leagueDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let league = LeagueInfo(leagueID: key, leagueDict: leagueDict)
                    self.leagueInfo.append(league)
                }
            }

        }
        completion()
    })
}
```

}

And here is the function that is called when the VC is loaded and needs the first function to be called first before anything else can be run.

```
func getSummaryLeaderboard(completion: @escaping ()->()) {
    self.summaryLeaderBoards.removeAll()
    print("Get Summary Leaderboard called")

    leagueInfo.getUserLeagues {
        print("Step 3")
        print("League Count: \(self.userLeagues.leagues.count)")
        for league in self.userLeagues.leagues {


            print("League ID: \(league.leagueID)")
            self.leagueInfo.getLeagueInfo(leagueID: league.leagueID, completion: {
                let leagueInfoIndex = self.leagueInfo.leagueInfo[0]
                self.leagueEndDate = leagueInfoIndex.endDate
                print("league end date: \(self.leagueEndDate)")
                self.leagueImg = leagueInfoIndex.leagueImage
                print("league img: \(self.leagueImg)")
                self.leagueName = leagueInfoIndex.leagueName
                print("league Name: \(self.leagueName)")
                self.minRounds = leagueInfoIndex.leagueMinRounds
                print("league min rounds: \(self.minRounds)")
                self.leagueLeaderScore = leagueInfoIndex.leaderPardieScore
                print("league leader score: \(self.leagueLeaderScore)")
                print("League info run")

            })


            self.leagueMembers.getLeagueMembers(leagueID: league.leagueID, completion: {
                print("GET LEAGUE MEMBERS RUN")
                self.roundsRemaining = self.fillInRoundsRemaing(minRounds: self.minRounds, roundsPlayed: self.leagueMembers.getUserRounds(userID: currentUserKey))
                print("user rounds remaining: \(self.roundsRemaining)")
                self.userPosition = self.getCurrentUserPosition(userID: currentUserKey)
                print("user position: \(self.userPosition)")
                self.roundsPlayed = self.leagueMembers.getUserRounds(userID: currentUserKey)
                print("user rounds played: \(self.roundsPlayed)")
                self.totalMembers = self.leagueMembers.leagueMembers.count
                print("user total members: \(self.totalMembers)")
                self.userWinnings = self.getCurrentUserWinnings(userID: currentUserKey)
                print("USER WINNINGS: \(self.userWinnings)")
                self.userPardieScore = self.leagueMembers.getUserPardieScore(userID: currentUserKey)
                print("user pardie Score: \(self.userPardieScore)")

                let newSummaryLeaderboard = SummaryLeaderboard(leagueEndDate: self.leagueEndDate, roundsRemaining: self.roundsRemaining, leagueImg: self.leagueImg, leagueName: self.leagueName, userPosition: self.userPosition, leagueLeaderScore: self.leagueLeaderScore, userWinnings: self.userWinnings, roundsPlayed: self.roundsPlayed, totalMembers: self.totalMembers, userPardieScore: self.userPardieScore)
                self.summaryLeaderBoards.append(newSummaryLeaderboard)
                completion()
            })

        }
    }
```

You'll see me comments that say Step 1, Step 2 and Step 3... Obviously I need them to run 1 2 3... Right now they run 3,1,2 and I can not figure out why..

Thanks again! This has been driving me nuts for days now.

Comment: You need to invoke `completion` inside the `getGolferLeagues` closure, not outside it. The way it is now, you are calling `completion` before `getGolferLeagues` is done.

Comment: And inside `getSummaryLeaderboard` you call `completion()` inside the loop which mean you call it over and over. That's no good either.

Comment: Also you've using two of the exact same loops *for league in self.userLeagues.leagues.*; one in getUserLeagues and another in getSummaryLeaderboard. Without looking too far into the code, that seems redundant. Very important to note you're adding a .observe to all of those nodes by .value which means you are leaving an observer in place on every node so if any nodes change, the code in the closures will execute. You may want to consider observeSingleEvent instead. AND you're using an outdated version of Firebase.